# Change view when using WinForm and MVC

Tags: c#, winforms

As part of a school project, a group and I will develop a Windows application using C#.
We are not very experienced in C# but has some basic understanding for it. We do however have experience from other languages and platforms.

We would like to build an application in which the layout is split into two primary parts: the menu, which will reside to the left and the content which will be to the right.
The menu will be more or less static and when an entry in the menu is chosen, the content will be changed.

We have not been able to figure out the best way for achieving this nor have we been able to find good material on this. The idea is to have one window and add a view (as far as I can understand, this should be a UserControl?) to this window. This control will be the menu.

Now, our question is if anyone can point us in the right direction to achieve the navigation in the program. Say, when a menu entry is clicked, how will we change the content of the window and how will we manage which view is active? I suppose that every view (in the "content area") will have a controller.
We are interested in the "best practices" for this when using WinForms and the MVC pattern.

We hope that someone can help us further in this project.

Comment: If I were you I would seriously consider using WPF instead of winforms. It, and the use of the MVVM pattern, allows you to do some pretty impressive stuff with far less code than if you are using winforms. If you don't already know winforms then it might also be a slightly less steep learning curve as WPF is a better thought out framework (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @RussellTroywest Thank you for your suggestion. We have decided to use WPF instead and have have managed to set up basic navigation using [this article](http://www.sunmetablog.co.uk/?p=351). Maybe you should leave an answer as your comment really what solved the problem?

Comment: There you go - turned it into an answer. There's some stuff about debugging bindings on my blog as well. There's probably better info out there than my stuff but you might find it useful. There's a link to it in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would seriously consider using WPF instead of winforms.

It, and the use of the MVVM pattern, allows you to do some pretty impressive stuff with far less code than if you are using winforms. If you don't already know winforms then it might also be a slightly less steep learning curve as WPF is a better thought out framework (at least in my opinion).

If you go the WPF route spend some time getting to understand how bindings work and how to bind your ViewModel to the UI. Once you have a good understanding of proper UI separation you are able to do far more than you could with the old WinForms framework.

I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) quite useful when I first started looking at WPF. Especially the RelayCommand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms the options that you have got is:

-dynamically clearing forms and generating content on menu navigation

-using mdi container form, which can be parent to a number of child forms

If you are using for WPF you could use Pages in a Frame control loaded based on used menu selection. You could also use MVVM pattern to build your app.